# Passing (or converting) vb short date to sql 101

Tags: sql, datetime, reporting-services, date-conversion

I have an SSRS report that you can click on to drill down and see more details about a cell. To do this, when you click a cell it passes parameters that populate a SQL statement in another report.

One of the parameters that it passes is a short date, mm/dd/yyyy. My problem is when month or day do not have double digits. So....

> Short date = 1/1/2013
>
> SQL 101 format = 01/01/2013

When the short date is passed, it doesn't match the SQL version exactly so it doesn't find any records when it should.

This returns nothing:

> where convert(char(10),dt.DATE_CREATED, 101) like '1/1/2013'

BUT, this returns all of the rows I need:

> where convert(char(10),dt.DATE_CREATED, 101) like '01/01/2013'

My problem is I need to somehow do this conversion of adding these zeros within SSRS...

Comment: What database platform are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the VB function `DateTime.Parse`

`DateTime.Parse(Fields!yourValue.Value)`

Answer (score 0):

This fixed my problem:
convert(char(10),dt.DATE_CREATED, 101) = Convert(datetime, @day)

Comment: You should just store date types as date types in the database rather than string. :-)

Comment: They are stored as date time, but they are converted to mm/dd/yyyy format for the user. When SSRS passes this value to a new report it passes it as a string

Comment: Where do you convert to mm/dd/yyyy? In the SQL query?